# Not able to change object materials on keypress in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to change materials for a .obj loaded model on keypress, However for some reason it is only taking the first element in the material array on key press. I have made sure the looping is proper.

here is the [DEMO](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andyram08/neavik/master/issue.html), Please let me know if there is anyway to resolve this

[CODE](https://github.com/andyram08/neavik/blob/master/issue.html)

Comment: all four objects change color on Chrome

Comment: @gaitat im able to change one color on key press, are you able to change more than one color ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a keydown event is emitted and the "C" key is pressed, we traverse the object and check to see if the indexed child is a mesh and if its material name is "Book_Cover".

But the materials that we've assigned to the colors array didn't have a name so the code within the condition

```
if (child.material.name == "Book_Cover") { /*...*/ }
```

wasn't executed as expected.

### TL;DR

add the name property to your materials:

```
var MyColor = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        //...,
        name: "Book_Cover"
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer working great, had been stuck at this for a week. kudos!!

Comment: NP! To help debug code, I sometimes like to place console.log("something"); where my code isn't being executed as I expect it to be. From there, I will move the console.log("something"); up line by line until it's visible when my code is executing;

With your example, I just placed it outside the if(child.material.name=="Book_Cover"){ }. and kept pressing "C" and it worked as expected (alot of "something" logged in the console), so I figured that's where the problem was.

Comment: will remember this approach, thanks again Phaseshifter.